# Convert a string array to a int array

Tags: c++, linux, arrays, type-conversion

I'm trying to write a function that takes a string array as a parameter, converts it to a int array, and returns the new array. I thought it would be pretty simple with the use of "Atoi" but apperently you cant use it the way i tried to.

here is my code so far.

```
int GameHandler::convertToInt(string array[])
{
    int tmp=0;
    string arr[20]=array;
    int values[20];
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
        values[i]=0;

    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
        tmp=atoi(arr[i]);
        values[i]=tmp;

    }
    return values;
}
```

Here is the error msg i get from my compiler:

> GameHandler.cpp: In member function ‘int
>   GameHandler::convertToInt(std::string*)’: GameHandler.cpp:60:20:
>   error: conversion from ‘std::string* {aka std::basic_string*}’
>   to non-scalar type ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string}’
>   requested GameHandler.cpp:67:24: error: cannot convert ‘std::string
>   {aka std::basic_string}’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to
>   ‘int atoi(const char*)’ GameHandler.cpp:71:12: error: invalid
>   conversion from ‘int*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive] GameHandler.cpp:61:9:
>   warning: address of local variable ‘values’ returned [enabled by
>   default]

Comment: Did you try understanding the error codes?

Comment: The function doesn't take an array of strings, it takes a pointer to a string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use arrays in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

The signature of atoi is

```
int atoi(const char *str);
```

Thus you need to pass a const char* to atoi, in your case:

```
tmp=atoi(arr[i].c_str());
```

Comment: i replaced the line with tmp=atoi(arr[i].c_str());
Still get errors tho when i compile.

Answer (score 0):

You need get the underlying `const char*` of the  `std:string`. You can do it with the `c_str()` method in the `std:string` class.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/

Comment: cplusplus.com is not regarded as reputable source for information on C++

Answer (score 0):

What might work for you is this solution with a (better) static function:

```
const int ELEM_CNT = 20;
static void convertToInt(string const strings[ELEM_CNT], int ints[ELEM_CNT])
{
  for (int i=0; i<ELEM_CNT; ++i)
    ints[i] = atoi(strings[i].c_str());
}


[...]
string sArr[ELEM_CNT];
int iArr[ELEM_CNT];
convertToInt(sArr, iArr);
```

Be careful about the following things:

- int values[20]; // this is an array on the stack whose memory is not usable outside the enclosing block (e.g. function)
- string array[] // array of unknown size; for dynamic sizes (set at runtime) you might want to use std::vector, which knows its size by size() member function

Answer (score 0):

As well as the `atoi` error, this line is also incorrect.

```
string arr[20]=array;
```

You cannot copy arrays like this in C++.

Just delete the above line and replace

```
tmp=atoi(arr[i]);
```

with

```
tmp=atoi(array[i].c_str());
```

There's no need to copy the string array for what you want to do.

Comment: Alright, done that, that took care of some of the errors
Now, the debbuger gives me the folowing error:

GameHandler.cpp:71:12: error: invalid conversion from ‘int*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest not to use C-style arrays.

```
void GameHandler::convertToInt(std::vector<int>& values, 
                              const std::vector<std::string>& array)
{
    values.resize(array.size());

    for(int i=0;i!=array.size();i++)
    {
        values[i]=atoi(array[i].c_str());
    }
}
```